# Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema unknown property 'optimization'

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to add webpack to my project for gannt chart syncfusion. But when I added the required versions, there were some errors, which are as follows.
the error :

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'optimization'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           optimization: ...
         }
       })
     ]
 - configuration.node should be an object.
 - configuration.output has an unknown property 'futureEmitAssets'. These properties are valid:
   object { auxiliaryComment?, chunkFilename?, crossOriginLoading?, chunkLoadTimeout?, devtoolFallbackModuleFilenameTemplate?, devtoolLineToLine?, devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate?, filename?, hashDigest?, hashDigestLength?, hashFunction?, hashSalt?, hotUpdateChunkFilename?, hotUpdateFunction?, hotUpdateMainFilename?, jsonpFunction?, library?, libraryTarget?, path?, pathinfo?, publicPath?, sourceMapFilename?, sourcePrefix?, strictModuleExceptionHandling?, umdNamedDefine? }
   Options affecting the output of the compilation. `output` options tell webpack how to write the compiled files to disk.
WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'optimization'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           optimization: ...
         }
       })
     ]
 - configuration.node should be an object.
```

I also used the webpack version in another project and it's a version of webpack.

```
"webpack": "~2.6.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.5",
"webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"
```

What must I do ? Is there a problem with the version?

Answer (score 0):

You mixing webpack 2 with webpack 4. Try to use all 3 package with webpack 4 version.

Example:

```
optimization: {
    minimizer: [
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            sourceMap: false,
            extractComments: 'all',
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: true,
                output: null
            }
        }),
        new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({
            cssProcessorOptions: {
                safe: true,
                discardComments: {
                    removeAll: true,
                },
            },
        })
    ]
},
```

You can view my full code [here](https://github.com/SaiGonSoftware/Awesome-CMS-Core/blob/master/src/AwesomeCMSCore/AwesomeCMSCore/webpack.config.js)